# Finder always opens as a small window on the top left corner of the screen

Tags: finder, windows, menu-bar, window-manager

Finder always opens as a small window on the top left corner of the screen. I adjust the window size, position, but after a while when I open the window again it opens as a small window on the top left corner by sticking to the menu.
This happens in any view mode: list, columns, etc. If I relaunch Finder it helps for a while, but then the problem comes back. It happens in Mojave, Catalina, Big Sur. This is terribly annoying.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It may be that someone or something has changed the permissions on the `.DS_Store` file in that particular directory.  Changes you make to window geometry and such are stored in that file.  If you made changes while logged in as another account, then that account may be the owner of that file.

But if you type `open /tmp` in Terminal, and you get the **same** window geometry, it’s probably something different.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I typed in Terminal `open / tmp` and got the response `The file / Users / User / tmp does not exist`, which blew my brain again. What could that mean?

Comment: `/tmp` exists.  There should be a space after `open` and no other spaces.  The error message had a space after `file` and no others.  When you separate parts with spaces, the O.S. thinks each part is a separate filename.  (Or directory name.)

Comment: Here is what output i got: 

`/tmp ; exit;
user@MacBook-Air-First ~ % /tmp ; exit;
zsh: permission denied: /tmp
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...      6 completed.`

Unfortunately, I can't understand what this means. And the problem with the geometry of the window still remains. 

I remembered that the problem with the geometry of the Finder window persisted even when I cleanly install macOS (not from a backup). Is it even possible that such a problem can be tied to an Apple ID?

Comment: Apparently we're not communicating very well.  Can you find a local tech-savvy Mac user to help you in person?  Or take it to an Apple store?

Comment: Okay, I'll try.